# EKEntityTypeEvent permission became EKAuthorizationStatusWriteOnly after iOS 17 update

Tags: objective-c, ekevent, ios17

I have an iOS app which displays the user's upcoming calendar events.

The app requests access to the user's calendar via (Objective-C):

```
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        // ...
    }
}];
```

Subsequently, the app would check whether the user had granted calendar access via:

```
NSInteger authorizationStatus = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
```

An `authorizationStatus` value of `EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` would indicate that we need to prompt the user for permission. A value of `EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` would indicate that the user had already granted calendar access.

After upgrading an iPhone that had been running this app on earlier iOS versions to iOS 17, the call to `[EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent]` started returning a new value: `EKAuthorizationStatusWriteOnly`. As the name implies, this value indicates that the app has "write-only" (no read access) permission on the user's calendar events.

Evidently, in iOS 17, the old `EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` response value has been split into two distinct values:

- `EKAuthorizationStatusFullAccess`, indicating full access
- `EKAuthorizationStatusWriteOnly`, indicating write-only access

I can see if I go into iPhone Settings > (My App) > Calendars, the app does indeed have "Add Events Only" permission.

[image: Settings Calendars screenshot showing the Add Events Only option selected]

It appears that, upon upgrade to iOS 17, the old "calendar access granted" permission had been automatically updated to the new "write-only access" permission.

While in this state, further calls to `requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent` silently (without showing the user a prompt) return a `granted` value of `NO`.

My question: Is the most graceful action that my app could take at this point be to show a message to the user suggesting that they manually go into their device's Settings > (My App Name) > Calendar, and select "Full Access"? Is there any better way to restore the previously-granted read-write access to the user's calendar? Or is my understanding of the current situation, as detailed above, incorrect in some way?